# RegEx match word in string containing + and - using re.findall() Python

Tags: python, regex, non-alphanumeric

myreg = r"\babcb\"

```
mystr = "sdf ddabc"

mystr1 = "sdf abc"

print(re.findall(myreg,mystr))=[]

print(re.findall(myreg,mystr1))=[abc]
```

Until now everything works as expected but if i change my reg and my str to.

```
myreg = r"\b\+abcb\"

mystr = "sdf +abc"

print(re.findall(myreg,mystr)) = [] but i would like to get [+abc]
```

I have noticed that using the following works as expected.

```
   myreg = "^\\+abc$"

   mystr = "+abc"   

   mystr1 = "-+abc"
```

My question: Is it possible to achieve the same results as above without splitting the string?

Best regards,

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

**There are two problems**

1. Before your `+` in `+abc`, there is no word boundary, so `\b` cannot match.
2. Your regex `\b\+abcb\` tries to match a literal `b` character after `abc` (typo).

**Word Boundaries**

The word boundary `\b` matches at a position between a word character (letters, digits and underscore) and a non-word character (or a line beginning or ending). For instance, there is a word boundary between the `+` and the `a`

**Solution: Make your Own boundary**

If you want to match `+abc` but only when it is not preceded by a word character (for instance, you don't want it inside `def+abc`), then you can make your own boundary with a lookbehind:

```
(?<!\w)\+abc
```

This says "match `+abc` if it is not preceded by a word character (letter, digit, underscore)".

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the following:

- `\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W` character
  (or vice versa).
- `\w` contains the character set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `\W` contains the character set `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, which means all characters except `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

`'+'` is not contained in `\w` so you won't match the boundary between the whitespace and the `'+'`.

To get what you want, you should remove the first `\b` from your pattern:

```
import re

string = "sdf +abc"
pattern = r"\+abc\b"
matches = re.findall(pattern, string)

print matches
['+abc']
```